# Finding the active window using python

Tags: python, window, python-os

I've been trying to create a program that will identify was the active program on my computer is.

I am writing this code on python. On a windows computer. 
I don't need the PID i only need the name of the program running. 
When i say active i mean the program that is currently being used by a user.

I will eventually be able to take the active program and open it using

```
import os
os.startfile("C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe") #skype for example
```

Comment: Did you try searching for something like "Python list processes"? Then you simply find the one named "skype.exe"

Comment: The list processes give me all the running programs. I only need one name of the program and I don't want to manually put in the name to find it

Comment: i just ran this code on a windows computer in spyder and i got the output "Active window: Spyder (Python 3.6)" -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/36419702/2601293

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find active window, You can use `win32gui` on windows ([find it in SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)):

```
import win32gui
window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
```

with `ctypes`:

```
pid = ctypes.wintypes.DWORD()
active = ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
active_window = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(active,ctypes.byref(pid))
```

Comment: try this: ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()

Comment: When i used that code by itself, it returned a number, what is that number and how would i instead get a file name

Comment: I was able to use win32gui but still, what about the number i get, what is that and how do i get the name

Comment: @JonathanKirshner read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501191/how-to-get-windows-window-names-with-ctypes-in-python

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand, how do i get a program name?

Comment: @JonathanKirshner you can get it by `GetWindowText`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/inaz2/6f72f18af15c47ab7432