# Python pyautogui window handle

Tags: python, windows, pyautogui

Using pyautogui is there a way to get a handle to a window so that I can ensure that a click is performed on that window only? In other words, if my window isn't in focus, then the click does not occur. Additionally, if my window isn't in focus then I bring it into focus and then perform the actions.

The way to identify a window could be an ID, window title etc similar to this https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm

Is there any other Python module that supports this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any other Python module that supports this kind of functionality?

https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto

https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#some-similar-tools-for-comparison lists as other similar Python tools:

- [PyAutoGui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) - a popular cross-platform library (has image-based search, no text-based controls manipulation).
- [Lackey](https://github.com/glitchassassin/lackey) - a pure Python replacement for Sikuli (based on image pattern matching).
- [AXUI](https://github.com/xcgspring/AXUI) - one of the wrappers around MS UI Automation API.
  winGuiAuto - another module using Win32 API.

Comment: First link is down

Comment: Note that pywinauto needs python 3.8.2+ because of a bug that was introduced to python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62037461/getting-error-while-running-a-script-which-uses-pywinauto/62083120#62083120

Answer (score 20):

This code might help to get what window you want to minimize or maximize. Example: If you want to get a Chrome window titled "Stack Overflow",

```
    pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Stack Overflow")[0].minimize()
```

Or if you want to minimize or maximize any file explorer window that titled "music", the same thing applies.

```
    pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("music")[0].maximize()
```

If you are not sure about which window you require, you can get a list [using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501191/how-to-get-windows-window-names-with-ctypes-in-python)

Comment: I should note that these functions are undocumented and the API might change in a future version of PyAutoGUI.

Comment: As of 2019, module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'getWindow'

Comment: Now it's called pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle

Comment: I got error > AttributeError: module 'pyautogui' has no attribute 'getWindowsWithTitle'

Answer (score 14):

PyAutoGui itself says, in its documentation's [FAQ section](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html),

> Q: Can PyAutoGUI figure out where windows are or which windows are visible? Can it focus, maximize, minimize windows? Can it read the window titles?
>
> A: Unfortunately not, but these are the next features planned for PyAutoGUI. This functionality is being implemented in a Python package named PyGetWindow, which will be included in PyAutoGUI when complete.

Now, if you go on over to [PyGetWindow's repo](https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow), you'll see there's no code there yet, but there is a [random_notes.txt](https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow/blob/master/random_notes.txt) file, with this pointer:

> Finding window titles on Windows:
>
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37501191/how-to-get-windows-window-names-with-ctypes-in-python

which has some interesting information.  (I haven't tried it yet.)

Comment: The mentioned entry in FAQ is't there anymore and https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/CHANGES.txt says: 'v0.9.43, 2019/05/27 -- Renamed getFocusedWindow to getActiveWindow to keep it up to date with pygetwindow.'

Answer (score 0):

In order to use pyautogui on app pages that are already maximized but not in focus First Minimize ten Maximize:

```
pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("FileZilla")[0].minimize()
pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("FileZilla")[0].maximize()
```

Answer (score 0):

A hybrid pyautogui/win32gui solution for **Windows**:

- if window is minimized, restore it
- then focus on it using a single win32gui call, passing in the window handle

```
import pyautogui
import win32gui
import time

window = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Your Window Title")[0]
rect = window._rect
if rect.x == -32000 or rect.y == -32000: # minimized check
    window.restore()
    time.sleep(1)      # if restoring, need to wait briefly to set to foreground
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(window._hWnd)
```