# pywinauto TypeError: item 2 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, pywinauto

I'm using pywinauto.

Python 3.7.6
pywinauto 0.6.8

I have no issue import pywinauto module,but have following issue:

code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application(backend="uia").start("thinkorswim.exe")
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 121, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]
KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'ctypes.c_long'>, <class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'comtypes.LP_POINTER(IUIAutomationCondition)'>), 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)
  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
TypeError: item 2 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.
```

Any friend can help?

Answer (score 2):

This is known Python bug fixed in later versions (3.7.7+ or 3.8.2+). See my answer here: [Getting error while running a script which uses pywinauto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62037461/3648361)

Note that you probably need **clean** installation of newer Python.